# Access a cell inside table using JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery

Good Morning. I'm trying to access a cell inside the table to insert data. But it's not working. What is the correct way to access a cell within a table in HTML using JQUERY?

Thank you all.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id='rxc021'>text</td>
<td id='rxc022'>button</td>
<td id='rxc023'>button</td>
</td>
</tr>

                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "inc_tessera.php",
                        data: { id_socio_tessera: document.getElementById("frmId").value } ,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(response){
                          if (response == "") {
                             $('table > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
                                var celula = "rxc2" + index;
                                alert(celula.html());

                             });                                 
                             $.MessageBox('La tessera è stata creata correttamente.');
                          }       
                        },
                        error: function(){
                                // alert('no');
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Your selector should work, unless you do not have `tbody` in it. Show your HTML and specify what exactly does not work

Comment: if your selector for rows is working, anyway to get the element corresponding to the cell you should then query for td elements inside the row while you just filled the `celula` variable with a string expecting to have the `html()` function

Comment: with jQuery, inside that `.each` loop you should do something like `$(tr).find('td').each(...)`

Comment: I can't read inside the cell. celula.html() doesn't work.

Comment: It should be 
$(celula).html()

Comment: Hi diegod. Could you show a sample, please?

Comment: Your table does not have `tbody` so selector is wrong

Comment: the html you included when you edited the question was malformed so I just slightly changed the content to make it valid. Now given that html, the proper way to fetch the value of the first cell in the first row of that table is: `$('table tr:first-child td:first-child').text()` ... now you should be aware that using id on td elements isn't very nice because td are supposed to repeat on several rows and ids should be unique so my selector doesn't use the id. Plus the each loop on rows was not needed if I correctly understand the question the way you changed it later

Comment: @diegod You should not fix OP questions as it will change final answer to question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('table > tr > td').each(function(index, td) { 
    
    var cell = $(td).text();
    var column = $(td).closest('tr');
    
    alert(`cell value is: ${cell}`)
    
 });
```